# how to display min of a column and use max of the same column to filter other attributes in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by

Input:

```
ID  CREATED_TIME  CANCELED_TIME

1       4             10

1       8             2

1       6             -1

1       3             7

2       5             null

2       4             8
```

Desired output:

```
ID  CREATED_TIME  CANCELED_TIME

1       3             2

2       4             null
```

so I basically want to display id, min(created_time) and canceled time of the row where created_time is maximum for each user? please provide the answer in PostgreSql and MySql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `canceled_time` where `created_time` has the maximum value, I would suggest the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select id, min(created_time),
       substring_index(group_concat(canceled_time order by created_time desc), ',', 1) as canceled_time
from table
group by id;
```

This will not work in all cases using default settings, because there is a maximum length for the `group_concat()` intermediate result.  However, it does work on most reasonable data sets and definitely for the data in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query to find each id's max created_time:

```
SELECT 
      ID, 
      created_time,
      MIN(CANCELED_TIME) AS MinTimeCanceled
FROM 
    tableName t1
WHERE created_time = (select max(created_time) from tableName t2
                      where t1.ID = t2.ID)
GROUP BY 
    ID, created_time
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a **TOTALS** or **GROUP BY** Query. Something like,

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Min(CREATED_TIME) As MinimumCreationTime
    Min(CANCELED_TIME) As MinimumCancelledTime
FROM
    yourTableName
GROUP BY
    ID;
```

Comment: One of the conditions was that the createdtime is a maximum for each row , your querry will not do that

Comment: @Nightmaresux, the OP has edited the Post since answer was published. So the query is irrelevant I understand. Will look into it. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.